# Ruby on Rails: has_one show error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, associations, show, has-one

I have a problem with the has_one association.

In my User model I have defined:

```
has_one :category
```

In the user_form is:

```
= f.select: category, options_for_select(Category.all.collect{|c|[c.name, c.id]}, @user.category), prompt: 'choose'
```

If I want, however it displayed in the index with:

```
user.category
```

I get following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: categories.user_id: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately I do not know where my problem is.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because you associated `categories` to `users` records with `has_one` relationship, so Rails expect `categories` table to contain `user_id` foreign key column, which is not present, as the error message says.

You should generate migration adding `user_id` column to `categories` table:

```
bundle exec rails generate migration add_user_id_to_categories user:references
```

and run it:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Ok, now i changed my index to user.category.name and i get NilClassError:
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @user3193137 that's what happens if user doesn't have its category.

Comment: If i, just for fun, change the save variable for f.slect from :category to :name it saves it right and shows me the value, but it seems like it cannot save it when i write f.select :category